# Do we need all the data in memory for running group by on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run a group by operation on a huge data (around 50TB) something like this

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(df['col1'], df['col2']).sum('col3')
```

I'm using the dataframe API on Pyspark and running this on EMR with 12 r5.4xlarge machine. The job takes a long time to process and eventually killed with OOM.

My question is: 
Is there any best practices on running group by operation with Spark?
Do we need all the data to fit in memory when running this?

Comment: You don't, it's a distributed operation. And that's the best it can get with only pyspark

Comment: My guess would be that id doesn't break because of this line especially, what is the rest ?

Answer (score 0):

The groupBy operation is not efficient for such large datasets. The OOM in groupBy indicates that there might be data skewness and this is because the groupBy implementation reads all the data in a partition in memory. You can take a look at the implementation here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L731